# How to deal with GNOME extensions and themes when upgrading Ubuntu?

Tags: gnome, upgrade, themes

I am thinking to upgrade from Ubuntu Focal Fossa to Groovy Gorilla, and I see that GNOME will change from 3.36 to 3.38.

I know that the themes and extensions I have are for GNOME 3.36. I am worried that I'll break the GUI if I straight up go through with this upgrade.

What is the most painless way to deal with this?
Open to all suggestions.

Comment: There are not usually issues with themes, gnome extensions are more the concern (you don't mention extensions though so if you're using the default extensions I would not expect a problem).

Comment: FYI:   details in the heading should also exist in your question... your actual question mentions only themes (but on closing the page I note your heading also mentions extensions... on some devices/browsing setups the heading does not show when the page is open so all details should exist in your actual question).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Themes that you used in GNOME 3.36 most likely won't break your GUI with GNOME 3.38, as GUI changes from 3.36 to 3.38 are rather subtle. If you find any glitches with the theme you use, you can contact the theme's developer or, if the glitches are serious, use another theme.

Regarding the extensions, first you should check if your extensions support GNOME 3.38. To do that, go to your [Installed Extensions](https://extensions.gnome.org/local/) in your browser, click on an extension and check the Shell versions it supports.

[image: Extension Shell version support]

If the *Shell version* dropdown contains *3.38* (as in the above screenshot), then the extension supports GNOME 3.38 and should work fine.

If *3.38* is not contained in the *Shell version* dropdown, it doesn't necessarily mean that the extension will not work in 3.38, as many extensions continue to work even for unsupported versions.

**What I suggest**, besides the above, is that you boot a Live Ubuntu 20.10 USB or create an 20.10 virtual machine (for example with VirtualBox) and install your extensions and themes there. You will immediately and safely see if everything works as you want and if it's worth upgrading to that version.

Answer (score 2):

The preferred way to upgrade typically is to reinstall **fresh**, then reconfigure your system. This has the enormous benefit that you start with a configuration that has been fully tested by the developers. This also has the benefit of a cleanup. Old configuration files are gone and have no chance to interfere with your new installation.

If you insist on **upgrading**, that is supported as well. Note that that may eventually incur some issues in the new installation, and not with theming alone. Still, the chance that there is an issue with the GTK theming is very small. For sure, there is essentially no chance that your custom theming would "break your GUI" in a sense that you would not be able to use it.

Comment: How would you suggest I prepare the system such that I can avoid problems after upgrade? I would really like to avoid a fresh install.

Comment: I said" chance of issues is very small" and "even if there are issues, they will never break your system". So just upgrade normally, and you will see. Very likely, your theme will work. If it doesn't, then change it.

Comment: I meant for the other issues you were talking about @vanadium

Comment: Your current question is about extensions and themes. Other issues can be many, usually small but occasionally severe. None you can anticipate. The upgrade process will automatically shut down third party repositories.